# Custom Delegate Does Not Receive a Call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

My custom delegate does not receive a call. Here is my setup. `ViewController` has a `SliderView` object which is a subclass of `UIScrollView`:

SlideView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SlideViewDelegate <NSObject
@required
-(void) didTapImageData:(NSMutableArray*)imageData atIndex:(int)index;
@end

@interface SliderView : UIScrollView<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
   __weak id<SlideViewDelegate> slideViewDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SlideViewDelegate> slideViewDelegate;

@end
```

SlideView.m

```
#import "SliderView.h"
@implementation SliderView
@synthesize slideViewDelegate;

- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"tapped");
   [[self slideViewDelegate] didTapImageData: imageData atIndex:0 ];
}
```

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <
                                        UIScrollViewDelegate,
                                        SlideViewDelegate>{
   SliderView *thumbGalleryView;//delegate and reference are set in XCode
}
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController

-(void)didTapImageData:(NSMutableArray*) imageData atIndex:(int)index{
    NSLog(@"NOT WORKING HERE");
}
```

So `ViewController` never receives a call at the method above. The `thumbGalleryView` is linked to `ViewController` and delegate is set to `ViewController` too. `SlideView`'s `handleTap` is printing message fine but `[[self slideViewDelegate] didTapImageData: imageData atIndex:0 ];` is ignored. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `delegate` which is `ivar` of scroll view.

You have to set the `slideViewDelegate` to `ViewController`

---

**Edited**

Add `IBOutlet`

```
IBOutlet __weak id<SlideViewDelegate> slideViewDelegate;
```

Then from your xib connect `slideViewDelegate` to `ViewController`
Also remember to change the class of scroll view to `SliderView`
Added Image for clarity
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Double-check where you set your delegate - if your delegate is `nil` at the time `-handleTap:` calls your `-didTapImageData:atIndex:` method, nothing will happen.

Comment: Yes, delegate us `null`. OK, but I dragged a delegate reference to ViewController. Where would the problem be?

Comment: I doubt you dragged a slideViewDelegate link within IB. So make sure that that property is set properly. Otherwise didTapImageData ist just sent to nil which does not do anything.

Comment: I dragged `thumbGalleryView` in IB, not `slideViewDelegate`. Is it wrong? The `thumbGalleryView` is `SliderView` which has a delegate.